# How and where to propose feature requests for GNU gdb

Tags: gdb, gnu, issue-tracking

I'd like to post a feature request to the gdb core development team. How and where can I do this?

I'm already on their mailing list for patches. (`gdb-patches@sourceware.org`) Is there a specific email format that they desire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How and where can I do this?

If your feature request is just "it would be nice if GDB did this...", then open a "Feature Request" bug in gdb [bugzilla](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla).

On the other hand, if you have a patch that implements your feature, mail it to `gdb-patches@sourceware.org`.

> Is there a specific email format that they desire?

No.